# Using Axios to delete users in React

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I have a list of users for my website, however, whenever I try to make my Axios call to delete a user, I am getting stuck with an HTTP 405 Error. I believe it may have to do with how I am attempting to use the id.

User component:

```
const Users = () => {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState({ list: [] });

    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get('/api/User')
            .then(response => {
                setUsers({list:response.data});
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            })
    }, []);

    const handleDelete = () => {

        axios
            .delete('/api/User', users.list.id)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.status)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }
    return(
        <div className="container white">
            <h3 className="center"> User List</h3>
                {users.list.map(item => (
                    <div className="section" key={item.id}>
                    <div className="divider"></div>
                        <h5>{item.username}</h5>
                        <h5>{item.email}</h5>
                        <button className="btn-delete" onClick={handleDelete}>Delete</button>
                    </div>
                ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

https://gyazo.com/2196c842804c7bfdfb1eb6b19ce26853

Comment: Are you able to debug and log the API?  Is the id hitting your endpoint?

Comment: Looks like your API type something else then Delete.

Comment: `HTTP 405 Error` means `Method Not Allowed` and in this case it means that, your server side implementation (route/endpoint for `'/api/User'`) is not declared using `delete` method. Also, check the dev-consol's network tab and see what your browser sends. Assuming you are using a framework on server.

Comment: I added a gyazo link showing that I was hitting the endpoint and getting the 405

Comment: Thats actually not a proof. It rather indicates that you reached the server but it couldn't find a delete endpoint. Can you show your API endpoint for the delete method?